# Download only the first few bytes of an Azure Blob

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I need to search many millions of jpeg files stored in Azure Blob Storage to find ones that are corrupt. It is a specific type of corruption where all the bytes in the file are 0. I should be able to tell if the file is corrupt by inspecting the header, which is in the first several bytes of the file. I don't want to have to download the entire file since it will cost money and time to do so.

I'm using the Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob, v 11.1.2 NuGet package and have seen a few methods that looked promising, such as `CloudBlockBlob.DownloadToByteArrayAsync` and `CloudBlockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync`, but it appears to download the entire file (well, `DownloadToByteArrayAsync` threw an Exception because I hoped I could give it a small array).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think [DownloadRangeToStreamAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblob.downloadrangetostreamasync?view=azure-dotnet-legacy) and [DownloadRangeToByteArrayAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblob.downloadrangetobytearrayasync?view=azure-dotnet-legacy) are what you're looking for.

Comment: @nlawalker I think so to. I found them after posting this question. If you write it up as an answer, I'll probably mark it as the one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [DownloadRangeToStreamAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblob.downloadrangetostreamasync?view=azure-dotnet-legacy) and [DownloadRangeToByteArrayAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblob.downloadrangetobytearrayasync?view=azure-dotnet-legacy). "Range" is the key term here, as it refers to the HTTP `Range` header, which broadly captures the notion of only downloading part of a resource. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/specifying-the-range-header-for-blob-service-operations) for how the SDK works under the hood with the Blob REST API.